# Is there a way to reuse data annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, data-annotations, code-reuse

Is there a way to implement the idea of a data domains (at a property level) inside of a class that is used as a model in a view in ASP.Net MVC 4?

Consider this code:

```
public class LoginProfileModel {

    [DisplayName("Login ID")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Login ID is required.")]
    public string LogonID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be blank.")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a LoginProfileModel in for ASP.Net MVC 4.  It uses a variety of metadata/data annotations so that I can create a clean view with this code:

```
@model myWebSite.Areas.People.Models.LoginProfileModel

@using ( Html.BeginForm( "Index" , "Login" ) ) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

I use the idea of a "Login ID" and a "Password" in more than one view, and therefore, in more than one view model.  I want to be able to define the attributes that a Password uses, or possibly the Password itself with all of it's data annotations in a single location so that I can reuse all those definitions where needed, rather than respecifying them every time they are used:

```
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be blank.")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Is that possible some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following attributes affect the validation process of your View.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be blank.")]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
```

For the Validation attributes, you can create a class like this:

```
public class PasswordRuleAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {    
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {

            if (new RequiredAttribute { ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be blank." }.IsValid(value) && new StringLengthAttribute(20) { MinimumLength=3 }.IsValid(value) )
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

You can use it as follows:

```
[PasswordRule]
public string Password{get;set;}
```

The other two attributes that you mentioned are Directly derived from the `Attribute` class, and I don't think there's a way to consolidate them into a single attribute.

I'll update you with an edit soon.

So now we're left with:

```
[DisplayName("Password")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[PasswordRule]
public string Password{get;set;}
```

EDIT:

According to this post: [Composite Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497281/composite-attribute), it's not possible to merge attributes.

Comment: Remarked this one as the best answer after poking at it for a while.  It allows me to centralize the validation logic, which is ultimately what I'm after.

Comment: Nice idea for separating the field validation.  Would be great if we could have a reusable `[DisplayName]` technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a buddy class, which provides metadata for your view model.  Like so:

```
public partial class LogonMetaData
{
    [DisplayName("Login ID")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Login ID is required.")]
    public string LogonID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be blank.")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then your view models:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[MetadataType(typeof(LogonMetaData))]
public partial class FirstViewModel
{
    public string LogonID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[MetadataType(typeof(LogonMetaData))]
public partial class SecondViewModel
{
    public string LogonID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Note the use of `partial` in the class definitions.  This is what allows this approach to work.  One caveat, other than the obvious problem with DRY, is that I believe the metadata class has to reside in the same namespace as your view models, else it complains.  Other than that, this should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As a corollary to John H's answer, you could just use inheritance and make those view models that have the "idea of a LogonId and password" inherit from that base view model.  This would solve the MetaData issues that were mentioned in the previous answer.

```
      public class LoginProfileModel {

        [DisplayName("Login ID")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Login ID is required.")]
        public string LogonID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be blank.")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public SomeOtherClassThatNeedsLoginInfo : LoginProfileModel{

         public string Property {get;set;}
}
```

Now in the SomeOtherClassThatNeedsLoginInfo, those properties and their related DataAnnotations will be available to you.

Another idea would be just to pass that LoginInfo as a property on your other view models.

```
public SomeOtherClassThatNeedsLoginInfo{

             public string Property {get;set;}

             public LoginProfileModel LoginModel {get;set;}
    }
```